# SHA1 value for latin characters in SQL server not matching with SHA1 of snowflake database

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sha1, hashbytes

I am trying to match the sha1 values of certain data in the table in SQL Server and Snowflake.

I've got the sha1 for a latin character in SQL server in the following way-

```
select  sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('SHA1',cast('á'  as varchar(1))),1,0)
```

This returns b753d636f6ee46bb9242d01ff8b61f715e9a88c3

The sha1 function in Snowflake returns a different value for the same character.

```
select sha1(cast('á' as varchar))
Result - 2b9cc8d86a48fd3e4e76e117b1bd08884ec9691d
```

Note - The datatype in SQL Server is nvarchar while  the datatype in Snowflake is varchar with default collation.
For english characters, the sha1 values match after casting nvarchar to varchar. However, this is not the case with latin characters.

Is there a way to match sha1 values for non-english characters ? I need to get the value '2b9cc8d86a48fd3e4e76e117b1bd08884ec9691d' in SQL Server 2017 & below as it is what other databases like Oracle, Snowflake and Hive return.

Thanks

Comment: What is the default collation of the database where you run this? Or column collation, which you read it from, whichever the case.

Comment: The result depends on collation and data type: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8d764690284cfb548551249631a2e70)

Comment: Default collation for the database as well as the said column is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in SQL server with datatype nvarchar while the collation in snowflake is utf8 with datatype varchar

Comment: select  sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('SHA1',cast(N'á' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8 as varchar(100))),1,0) works fine on dbfiddle. However, SQL server 2017 does not seem to support this UTF8 collation. Is there any alternatives here?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Never use `varchar` when calculating hashes. There are simply too many rakes you can step on in the process.

Just as an example, I adapted your code for easier understanding and run it in the context of a database which has `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` default collation:

```sql
declare @a nchar(1) = N'á';
declare @b char(1) = cast(@a as char(1));

select @b as [Char], ascii(@b) as [A], unicode(@b) as [U], HASHBYTES('SHA1',@b) as [Hash]
union all
select @a, ascii(@a), unicode(@a), HASHBYTES('SHA1',@a);
```

The result is:

```
Char    A    U Hash
---- ---- ---- ------------------------------------------
á     225  225 0xB753D636F6EE46BB9242D01FF8B61F715E9A88C3
á     225  225 0xA4BCF633D5ECCD3F2A55CD0AD3D109A108A45F02
```

However, if I change the database context to another DB, with the `Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS` collation, the same code suddenly returns different values:

```
Char    A    U Hash
---- ---- ---- ------------------------------------------
a      97   97 0x86F7E437FAA5A7FCE15D1DDCB9EAEAEA377667B8
á      97  225 0xA4BCF633D5ECCD3F2A55CD0AD3D109A108A45F02
```

As you can see, the [Char] in the first line is a different character now (small Latin "а"). This kind of implicit codepage adjustment cannot be prevented unless your data is in Unicode, or in a binary form.

---

**Your options**

1. Upgrade to MS SQL Server 2019, or move to Azure SQL Database. Starting from this version, you can actually store strings in UTF-8 encoding, although you'll probably get a performance hit for that (whether it'll be noticeable or not, depends on your usage patterns).
2. Calculate hashes externally (meaning, not in SQL). You can write a CLR function in C#, or something similar in Java (see Elliott Brossard's answer). This will increase complexity of your solution, and putting external code in your database might not be allowed by your company's policies, for example. Plus, maintaining external assemblies is usually a hassle.

Comment: Thank you Roger for the explanation. In this case, I am trying to compare the hash values of **á** across both the databases and I am trying to know why they give different hash results. I am looking for a way to match these values and I would like to know if it is possible either by changing the collation/datatype etc. My use case requires matching the hash values to establish that data is same.

Comment: Convert them both to `nvarchar` *before* you hash then, @Happygolucky .

Comment: @Larnu snowflake does not support nvarchar and the equivalent of this datatype in snowflake is varchar

Comment: @Happygolucky, Snowflake docs state that `VARCHAR holds Unicode characters.`, so the only issue I see here is that it stores strings in UTF-8. Unless you have SQL Server 2019 or latest Azure equivalent, you can't use the same encoding for strings on this side. I'd recommend to understand what they call collations, seems to be a bit different concept - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html

Comment: @RogerWolf yes, I tried some permutations with different collations - `select  sha1(cast('á' collate 'en' as varchar))`. It seems as though changing the collation does not affect the hash output in Snowflake. All of them seem to give the same output.

Comment: @RogerWolf Option1 is not feasible as of now. Option 2 given in  Elliott Brossard's answer returns the same output like SQL server. However, since my use case requires pushing the computation part to database and just comparing the results, it will increase the complexity of the solution as you rightly guessed.

Comment: @Happygolucky, it takes a bit more to convert strings to UTF-8 in C#, as natively they are also stored in UTF-16 in .NET. However there are plenty of examples on SO on how to do that. And if you'll make a CLR function, it'll be executed inside SQL Server (can be called directly from your SQL code).

Answer (score 0):

You can compute SHA1 hashes of Latin-1 strings using a Java UDF. Here is an example:

```sql
create function latin1sha1(str varchar)
returns varbinary language java handler = 'Latin1Sha1.compute' as $$
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

class Latin1Sha1 {
  public byte[] compute(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    hash.update(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));  // AKA Latin-1
    return hash.digest();
  }
}
$$;

select hex_encode(latin1sha1('á'));
```

This returns `B753D636F6EE46BB9242D01FF8B61F715E9A88C3`.

Comment: Doesn't look like you convert it to UTF-8. I receive this hash in SQL Server from `nvarchar` data.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Yes, this is the value SQL Server 2017 and below versions return. I need to get the hash value `2b9cc8d86a48fd3e4e76e117b1bd08884ec9691d` which is what Snowflake, Oracle and Hive SQL queries return as the SHA1 output for the same `á`. The use case is to match the data between the databases by matching the hash values.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were asking. I thought your goal was to get the same hash value in Snowflake as you are seeing in SQL Server.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard. Ah, got it. The description was not very specific on the ask. Updated the same! Thanks.